# Mockito verify other function gets called with right parameter,when we call some function

Tags: scala, mockito, scalatest

If i have 2 functions. Function1 which calls function2. I need to write test case for them. I am using mockito. Trait.

Just a mimic of the stuff

[image]

Comment: You should have a clear question that details what the problem is. Also you should use stackoverflows code formatting instead of inserting image. Easier to read and copy from. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: I want to verify that on calling function1, function2 gets called with right parameters.

@thoredge Thanks for your input and will surely make a note of it.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer might be something you may not like:

Don't do it!

This is not a technical answer to your technical question, but a more strategical one.

You should test and evaluate a functions validity only based on it's observable behaviour,i. e. it's result.
To bind the validity on a specific structure[1] will make your implementation and your test extremely inflexible.

You would have rewrite your tests each time a change in implementation is done, even when no functional changes are made but only structural ones.
This renders your tests useless, because they do not assert the specified behaviour but only reflect your particular implementation.
That puts additional burden on any refactoring you have to make.

[1]like: "it calls function f with this parameter" or "it calls function g after f" or "it calls a function n times")

Comment: Your points are just bang on.Those are both pure methods that can be property-tested and there's surely no immediate reason to care whether one calls the other.

Comment: If *you* consider my answer "bang on" and know about property testing and what to care about in test, why did *you* ask the question in the first place?